# CSS How to have a text caption in the bottom of an image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to css and I am trying to have a text caption in the bottom of my images, like so:

[image: How I want it to look like]

I have 3 images in 3 different bootstrap columns.

```css
.img-preview {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 350px;
}
.img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-container img-preview" src="../img/Referenzen_Stimmungsbild.jpg">
      <h3><span>Maler<br />und<br />Tapezierarbeiten</span></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-container img-preview" src="../img/Referenzen_Stimmungsbild.jpg">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-container img-preview" src="../img/Referenzen_Stimmungsbild.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried a lot of possible solutions but nothing really worked.
Tried this for example https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/ but when I resized my window, the text caption didn't fit anymore.

What is the best way to achieve this effect?

Comment: In this instance your wrapper `div` needs to be relative, and your `h3` should be positioned absolutely. you can then specify bottom and left coordinates for the `h3`

Comment: However, displaying different lengths of texts in the same wrapper might be an issue depending on the text length. You might want to constrain this by using a set height and overflow hidden for example

Comment: Also `background-position: center top;` does not work with inline image elements (use for background images). ASFAIK.

Comment: you can use `background-image` and apply `img-container`, `img-preview` classes for the parent `div`  instead of `img` inside it with `h3` has absolute position at `left: 0; bottom: 0;`, the caption will show off as you want

Comment: tnx a lot. even its late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using **CSS Positioning**. But you need to change the structure a little bit. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.img-holder {
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.img-holder h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(65, 55, 91, 0.8);
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-preview {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.img-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"> 
      <div class="img-holder">
            <img class="img-container img-preview" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
            <h3><span>Maler<br />und<br />Tapezierarbeiten</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6"> 
      <div class="img-holder">
            <img class="img-container img-preview" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
            <h3><span>Maler<br />und</span></h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer this is just how I want it! Do you know how I can keep the background size of the text (purple background) the same on every image? Because sometimes it's just one line of text

Comment: @Insane The `width` will be same on every image, if you pass the `height` value on `.img-holder h3`, it will automatically fix its height as well.

Comment: I added height: 20% to .img-holder h3, but how do I now vertically center the text in the purple box?

Comment: @Insane Use `text-align: center` css rule on `.img-holder h3` for center aligning the text inside purple background.

Comment: Edited my comment, I meant vertically. Sorry

Comment: @Insane Updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 7):

you can simply do with `Position:absolute` , try with this answer

```css
.relative_box {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}
.relative_box img {
    width:100%;
}
.relative_box h3 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px
}
```

```html
<div class="relative_box">
    <img src="https://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg" alt="" />
    <h3><span>Maler<br />und<br />Tapezierarbeiten</span></h3>
</div>
```