# caption and border for image html

Tags: html

how to add border and caption to image in html like this in bbc website [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-38349993)

here is what i tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" style="border:0px solid black;border-right:0px solid black;border-bottom:10px solid black;border-left:0px solid black;">

</body>
</html>
```

but i was not able to add caption inside the border

little help here:

Comment: You cannot do that. You need to have two elements, one for caption and another for image

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy can you show me with code please : )

Comment: You should be able to code yourself with my little description help

Comment: Jjust check with this link. is this what you need  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41035741/6572922

Answer (score 3):

As @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy said, you will definitely need more elements in order to make that happen.

For example, here's a quick snippet I wrote to show how both the "border" caption and overlay caption can be done. (the "border" caption isn't actually a border)

```css
.image-container{
  width: 660px;
}
.image{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.caption{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba( 0,0,0,.4 );
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 4px;
}
.border-caption{
  background-color: black;
  padding: 15px 12px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/1E5A/production/_93007770_banki-moon.jpg" alt="Alt to the image" />
  <span class="caption">AFP PHOTO /UNITED NATIONS/ ESKINDER DEBEBE</span>
 </div>
 <span class="border-caption">UN Secretary-General Ban Ki-moon is pondering his options as his term comes to an end</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i am up voting because you gave the exact answer for the question . not only example

Comment: thanks you as Jishnu V S said you gave the exact answer thank you very much, but when i add with another picture the solid black caption is more than my picture can we make it responsive with picture size

Comment: I've updated my answer. There's no way to easily adjust all 3 boxes to the same size because no matter what, the image HAS to be bigger than the text you're adding. If your text is longer than the image, that's going to happen. The only way to avoid this is to set a width on the container. (This is how that website you linked does it) So I've added a way to adjust the size using the `.image-container` class. You can change the size and it'll work! You can set it to 100% if the column you're adding this to is small enough to have the image fit the full width.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid inline styles**

*add more elements for more flexibility*

```css
body {
  background: #131418;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5% auto
}
.mycontainer {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
.myimage {
  padding: 20px;
}
.mycaption {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
.mycontent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  max-width: 75%
}
.myimage,
.mycontainer,
.mycaption {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <img class="myimage" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <div class="mycaption">Caption #1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo perfecto adolescens intellegebat an, pro ne quot nominati scribentur. Est sumo graeci accommodare et. Nulla veniam legimus sed ex. Eruditi alienum sadipscing ea mel, sonet facete maluisset nam te. Usu ut utinam intellegat
      theophrastus. Cu vero invidunt pertinax eos, falli legimus pri id, corpora vivendum praesent id eum.
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <img class="myimage" src="http://placehold.it/250x350">
    <div class="mycaption">Caption #2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo perfecto adolescens intellegebat an, pro ne quot nominati scribentur. Est sumo graeci accommodare et. Nulla veniam legimus sed ex. Eruditi alienum sadipscing ea mel, sonet facete maluisset nam te. Usu ut utinam intellegat
      theophrastus. Cu vero invidunt pertinax eos, falli legimus pri id, corpora vivendum praesent id eum.
      <p>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontainer">
    <img class="myimage" src="http://placehold.it/450x550">
    <div class="mycaption">Caption #3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mycontent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo perfecto adolescens intellegebat an, pro ne quot nominati scribentur. Est sumo graeci accommodare et. Nulla veniam legimus sed ex. Eruditi alienum sadipscing ea mel, sonet facete maluisset nam te. Usu ut utinam intellegat
      theophrastus. Cu vero invidunt pertinax eos, falli legimus pri id, corpora vivendum praesent id eum.
      <p>
  </div>
</body>
```